# Excel Userform textbox data validation

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm creating an Excel Userform. I want to validate two textbox values.

```vb
if combobox1.text= 1 to 2yr then textbox2.value =>1 and <=2
combobox11.text= 3 to 10yr then textbox2.value =>3 and <=10
combobox1.text= 11 to 15yr then textbox2.value =>11 and <=15
combobox1.text= 16 to 20yr then textbox2.value =>16 and <=20
end if
```

[image: Userform]

Comment: hi, your syntax looks wrong ... but to help fix, it would be good to clarify what you're trying to achieve. Are you looking to set `textbox2.value` based on `textbox1.text`? ... or are you trying to validate both textboxes and do something else? And is a single number typed into `textbox1`? thanks

Comment: if age group text is 1 to 2yr then age must inbetween 1 to 2  if greater or lesser value then show me msg "  plz enter correct value "

Comment: Validation can be done better with KeyDown event.

Answer (score 1):

The general syntax needs to be something like the following:

```
If combobox1.Text = "1 - 2 yr" And (CDbl(textbox2.Value) < 1 Or CDbl(textbox2.Value) > 2) Then
    MsgBox ("Enter correct value")
ElseIf combobox1.Text = <another string> And <another range check> Then...
End If
```

Notes:

- You were missing quotes around the `combobox1.Text` value: you need this to compare to text (`String`).
- The `textbox2.Value` needs to be converted to a number (`Double`) to check the range.
- You'll need to consider adding validation on your inputs, in case the field is left blank, or other non-numeric values are entered.
- I haven't completed the full set of values for `combobox1`: you can use `ElseIf` to chain them together.
- Once you have the basic structure, you could refactor by writing a separate `Function`, named e.g. `CheckRange`, passing the value to check and the acceptable range, rather than repeating your code.
- As a way of refining, if you get this far, you could parse the acceptable range from the `checkbox1.Text` value. I wouldn't worry about this initially though.
  hth

Comment: thanks sir , it works great for all criteria except one , If combobox1.Text = "6 month - 1 yr" And (CDbl(textbox2.Value) < 0.6 Or CDbl(textbox2.Value) > 1) Then
    MsgBox ("Enter correct value"), it show me error msg. even i enter correct value eg = 0.7 , 0.8 , 0.9 ,0.10

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure - your code in the comment looks ok. Maybe if you edit your question and show your full code, that may highlight something? 
Also, do you mean an error message, or the MsgBox? If an actual error message, then you may need to check your input, e.g. no trailing spaces, as these may prevent the `CDbl` from working. 
Lastly, 0.10 wouldn't be in range: you're inputting a decimal, not the number of months.

Comment: yes sir , one spelling mistake done in code , thats why its show me msgbox. now code run perfectly ,

Comment: lastly u said "0.10 wouldn't be in range: you're inputting a decimal, not the number of months." so how can i use 0.10 , 0.11 values in above code

Comment: you can't _directly_ use 0.10 to represent 10 months ... as a number it is one tenth. For example, ten months as a decimal would be 10/12 = 0.83 ... and 0.10 as a fraction of a year is 1.2 months!  You could use two textboxes, one for years and one for months, and apply a calculation.

Comment: Alternatively, though I'm not sure if this is feasible for what you're attempting, you could re-think the user input. Have the user enter _just_ a date of birth, from which you can derive the age band, rather than having the user enter both age and age band.